# Is there any good add-ins in Visual C#2008?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, add-in

My visual assist x didn't work after I installed visual c# 2008.
Is there any good add-ins like VAX?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Visual Studio 2008 Comparison Chart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/aa700921.aspx) shows that the Express editions do not support addins.

You will have to purchase at least the Standard edition to use addins.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what you want to do with the add-ins.  My personal favorite is [ViEmu](http://www.viemu.com/) which makes Visual Studio respect the Vim keybindings.  It takes some getting used to, but once you have it down, the Vim way of doing things is extremely efficient.

Answer (score 0):

[Their homepage](http://www.wholetomato.com/) says it works with VS 2008. Maybe it was disabled? Tool menu... Add-ins Manager. Otherwise might try a reinstall. VS2005 and VS2008 Add-ins are in different spots in the registry so having an Add-in installed for VS2005 will not automatically make it available for VS2008.

Answer (score 0):

VAX works perfectly in VS 2008. maybe you need to reinstall or get a newer version.

Answer (score 0):

I've written [this](http://www.codeplex.com/lazy) simple add-in, hope you find it usable.